# HTML/CSS: Rectangle with fixed height, vertically/horizontally centered text, and min width that expands with inner text

Tags: html, css

Like the title says, I'm trying to make a rectangle with fixed height, vertically/horizontally centered text, and a minimum width that expands when the inner text would overflow. Also, I would like to be able to "dynamically" place this rectangle anywhere, so I don't want any absolute hard coding of coordinates.

This is what is I've tried so far: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G830P14CNCOT

The problems with it are: 
1) the text is not perfectly centered
2) content that doesn't fit in the rectangle is dropping down below it instead of increasing its width.

For convenience, this is the same code that is in the playground linked above:

```html
<html>
<style type="text/css">
  .container {
    min-height: 2em;
    position: relative; /* so center-area can be positioned absolute */
    min-width: 3rem;                     
    border-style: solid;
   border-width: 0.08rem;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #99d1ef;
  }
  .center-area {
    /* let it fill the whole container */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .center-area:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .centered {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #99dc60;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
</style>
  <body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="center-area">
   <span class="centered">
         short
   </span>
  </div>
 </div>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="center-area">
     <span class="centered">
         loooong
      </span>
     </div>
 </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.meh {
  min-height: 50px;
  display: inline-flex;
  min-width: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="meh">
  <span contenteditable="true">edit meh!</span>
</div>
```

w3schools is not [W3C](https://www.w3.org/).

While the latter are ***the*** organization responsible for implementing web standards, "the school" are a business, cashing in from adwords, trying to make a buck from the illusion they're somehow affiliated with the Consortium. In short, a parasite.

Because w3schools are a business, they need to pay editing their content and their content is more often than not... not exactly great.

If you're looking for a friendly and exhaustive learning resource (other than w3c's official [HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/) and [CSS](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/specs.en.html) docs - which might be too technical for beginners), consider using [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web).
Unlike w3schools, they are non-profit and have huge (free) support from the web development community, including all major browsers, ***and*** W3C.

Comment: Awesome solution! Also, thanks a lot for the tip. Will definitely be using it.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Flex-box to achieve this: i.e

HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">
  your long expanding text goes here!
</div>
```

css:

```
.flex-container {
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 5px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 2em;
    min-width: 3rem;                     
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.08rem;
    background: #99d1ef;
  }
```

Flex-box is really good and makes things simple. Instead of all the lines of code that you have written, see how simple the code looks with flex. For more details and reference on flex, use this link : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox